# How to make my code about 'arithmetic substrings' work quicker

Tags: c++

I have some problems with code for my classes. Even though it works correctly, I run out of time for half of the examples.
Here's the task (I really did my best trying to translate it):

You have a permutation of numbers 1,2,...,n for some n. All consecutive numbers of permutations together create sequence a1, a2, an. Your task is to count, how many arithmetic substrings of a sequence of length 3 exist.

Input:
In first line there is a number n (1 <= n <= 200 000). In the second line there is n numbers a1, a2...an representing our permutation.

Output:
The program needs to print out amount of arithmetic substrings of length 3 for permutations from entry. You can assume that the result won't be bigger than 1 000 000.

Is there any way to make it work faster? Thanks for help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int input_length;
    cin >> input_length;
    int correct_sequences = 0;
    
    bool* whether_itroduced = new bool[input_length + 1]{0}; // true - if number was already introduced and false otherwise.
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input_length; i++)
    {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        whether_itroduced[a] = true;
        int range = min(input_length - a, a - 1); // max or min number that may be in the subsequence e.g. if introduced number a = 3, and all numbers are six, max range is 2 (3 - 2 = 1 and 3 + 2 = 5, so the longest possible subsequence is 1, 3, 5)
        
        for (int r = range * -1; r <= range; r++) // r - there is a formula used to count arithmetic sequences -> an-1 = a1-r, an = a1, an+1 = a1+r, I have no idea how to explain it
        {
            if (r == 0) continue; // r cannot be 0
            
            if (whether_itroduced[a - r] && !whether_itroduced[a + r])
            correct_sequences++;
            
        }
    }
    cout << correct_sequences;
}
```

example
input:
5
1 5 4 2 3
output:
2
// 1,2,3 and 5,4,3

Comment: I don't understand the task. Could you give us an example of correct output for given input?

Comment: `bool* whether_itroduced = new bool[input_length + 1]{0}` ==> `std::vector<bool> whether_itroduced(input_length + 1);`

Comment: Have you run a profiler on your code?

Comment: Does this code work? Then probably Code Review is a better place, as that's for improvements to (seemingly) working code, whereas SO is more for problems with non-working code.

Comment: A double nested `for` loop is a sign that things will time out.  Unless you can prove that the time complexity is less than `O(n*n)`, you have an `O(n*n)` algorithm, and that rarely passes tests.  The solution is to come up with another algorithm that is less than quadratic in time.

Comment: I mean, I'm in middle school, so it shouldn't be such a difficult task. I guess that I'm just missing some way, to make it work quicker. Also, using vectors didn't help a lot. I'll try on Code Review later, thanks for info.

Comment: Why is output 2 for permutation 1 5 4 2 3? Why the array has to be a permutation?

Comment: I think that there is someone writing the task, made a mistake. The correct answer is that there are 2 substrings - 1, 2, 3 and 5, 4, 3. I don't really know how it's supposed to work.

Comment: i have no clue what an arithmetic substring is, and I am afraid that I am not the only one. As others said, to get better time complexity we have to work on the algorithm, not on the code, but for that we need to understand the problem you are solving better

Comment: Your comment about what constitutes an arithmetic substring does not seem to agree with your code.

Comment: Why not 1 5 4? 1 = 5 - 4...

Comment: ok I think I am getting closer. When input is `1 2 3 4 5` is that 1 arithmetic substring of minimum lenght 3 or 3 arithmetic substrings of lenght 3 ?

Comment: Oh arithmetic progression, now I get it.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 -> {1 2 3}, {2 3 4}, {3 4 5}, {1 3 5}, 4 substrings of length 3.

Comment: Oh yeah, arithmetic progression would make sense. Working with translator is really annoying. Sorry for trouble. Also when input is 1 2 3 4 5, the result should be 4 - 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 3 4 5; 1 3 5.

Comment: @amdlaihfgan *I mean, I'm in middle school, so it shouldn't be such a difficult task* -- To code up a slow solution that uses a nested loop, that is simple.  The problem with doing that it is simple, **and slow**.  So it isn't as simple as you may believe in many cases.  The goal of questions like this is to see if you can come up with a solution that doesn't require the amount of loop iterations you're using.

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely right. It's the most troublesome task I've done so far

Comment: @amdlaihfgan Do you have the test case where this times out?  Is it timing out due to the number of data items, or the number of data items is small and still is timing out?  If it is the latter, then maybe you have an off-by-one bug somewhere, and an infinite loop in some form is occurring.  If it's the first option, then the size of the data is what is causing this.

Comment: I can't really see the test cases, but the biggest 'n' is 33266. Guess that it's the matter of amount of the data.

Comment: @amdlaihfgan Visualize in your mind and draw your solution out on paper first before writing any code.  If you first sorted those numbers, is there a better solution than if the numbers were not sorted (your current code does not sort the numbers)?  Too many times, persons jump right into writing code, and too often than not, the code is inefficient or slow, because the solution was "easy" , and it was the first that came into their mind.  Sometimes using pictures and thinking outside the box needs to be done.